# Preprocess function for content type

Tags: theming

First of all this question is exact copy of [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27947/preprocess-function-per-content-type) (I'm sorry for that). But I don't get one thing.

My content-specific **theme function** works fine! 
I have a theme, called "nbttheme" and content type with machine name "nbt_text"

and declaration of

```
function nbttheme_node__nbt_text(&$variables) {
    return "hello";
}
```

does the work, I have only "hello" in node output. So the theme function EXISTS, contrary to what mr. Clive had said. Am I wrong?

And, if the theme function works then there must be a preprocess for it, called nbttheme_preprocess_node__nbt_text() but this doesn't work

So where am I wrong? It seems inportant for me and I want to understand Drupal's theming flow entirely.

P.S. This way has worked for with views, there is a template for row output in my project: views-view-fields--latest-additions.tpl.php, hence I would have had a nbt_views_view_fields__latest_additions() function for theming.

Comment: Have you tried to clear cache for theme registry?

Comment: Yes, I've done this several dozen times:)

Comment: Have you tried the theme developer (devel_themer) module? It will provide naming suggestions for template and preprocesss functions. If that doesn't work, please post what it does suggest so I have a better understanding of the problem.