# Pass custom variable from template.php to *.tpl.php

Tags: nodes, theming

template.php > THEMENAME_field_CONTENT_TYPE(&$variables)
I am trying to check each field as it passes through...

```
if( $variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_I_am_looking_for' )
{
    if( $variables['element'][0]['#title'] == 'value_I_am_looking_for' )
    $variables['newVariableName'] = 'NewVariableValue';
}
```

or for Booleans...

```
$variables['newVariableName'] = True;
```

But in *.tpl.php file, when I do this...

```
<?php if( isset( $content['isIcebreaker'] ) ): ?>
<pre>It's What You're Looking For!</pre>
<?php endif; ?>
```

...Nothing happens.

**Specific Details...**
The custom content type is called 'Netrunner Card' and all cards have 0 or more 'subtypes'. The subtypes field is a taxonomy_reference field. One of those subtypes is 'Icebreaker' and I'm trying to set $variables['isIcebreaker'] = True; whenever a card has the subtype of 'Icebreaker' and then test against that in node--netrunner-card--full.tpl.php.

Basically, in regular-speak, when a card has 'Icebreaker' as one of its subtypes, I want to add in some custom div's and other content in the node--netrunner-card--full.tpl.php for those cards. But the custom variable isn't making it over. I'm uncertain as to what I'm doing wrong.

**SIDE NOTE** If there is a better way to do what I am trying to do, I would appreciate those answers as well. However, regardless, I would still love to know the appropriate, Drupal Best Practices way of passing custom variables from template.php to a *.tpl.php file.

**CODE VIEW**
I have split off my template.php and included the new file as sort of an extended template.php. Here are posts of both my template.php and my tpl file.

[template_netrunner_card.php](http://codepad.org/Q5fWvM28)

[node--netrunner-card--full.tpl.php](http://codepad.org/nXNizjet)

**ANSWER:** [I used the preprocess_node function like so...](http://codepad.org/Bj8wVwpw)

Comment: The function you posted in your template.php isn't a preprocess function.

Comment: Ok. So... forgive my noobishness... what am I doing wrong? I don't understand the preprocess versus what I did... (aka how is that relevant?) Does this mean I am using a 'process' function? And is what I'm doing there make more sense in a preprocess? and how would I make it a preprocess function?

Comment: You'll want to implement hook_preprocess_field to adjust variables passed to a field. This will get called for all fields so you need to test the field name - `$variables['element'][field_name']` I think - to do anything that's specific for a particular field.

Comment: So could I just change the name of my current function in template_netrunner_card.php and go? Or are we talking about a complete rework? Or just add in a preprocess function for the part I am working on?

Comment: Change the function name to MYTHEME_preprocess_field and clear the cache, and you should then be able to manipulate the variables before they are passsed to the .tpl.php file.

Comment: I would rather not run this massive function on every field, just the ones for the content type 'netrunner card'

Comment: This has been discussed before for node preprocess: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27947/preprocess-function-per-content-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every element key in the root of the `$variables` array will be available in the template file as an actual variable. The mechanics behind this is in [`theme_render_template()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_render_template/7), which uses PHP's [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function on the theme's variables.

So when you look at `$content` in the template file, that corresponds to `$variables['content']` in the preprocess function.

Similarly, if you add `$variables['newVariableName']` in the preprocess function, it will be available at `$newVariableName` in the template file.

If you want to add it to the content array, you need to do so explicitly in the preprocess function, e.g. `$variables['content']['newVariableName'] = ...`

Bear in mind that the content array is supposed to be a [render array](https://drupal.org/node/930760), so that's probably not the best place for it. The way you have it currently is fine, just use `if (isset($newVariableName)):` in place of your current `array_key_exists` condition.

Your current method is considered best practice for passing variables from preprocess functions (whether in template.php or a module file) to template files, you don't need to change anything in your thinking there.

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is without seeing the full code. Could you dump the whole function into the question (including the signature)? Could just be you're not passing `$variables` by reference

Comment: Here is a sample page: http://netrunner.randomblink.com/node/143 This is an Icebreaker. There should be a little PRE tag loaded with 'It's an Icebreaker!' showing up on the page... but there isn't.

Comment: I can't tell whether you responded by editing your answer or not... but it still isn't working...

Comment: I'm using this: 

    if( $variables['element'][0]['#title'] == 'Icebreaker' )
    {
        $variables['isIcebreaker'] = True;
    }   

And it's still not going through... When I replace the $isIcebreaker variable = True with a dvm, the dvm runs. So I know I am firing at the right time. But in my tpl, it isn't rolling through.

Comment: Ok... to test even further... I went into THEMENAME_field_CONTENT_TYPE(&$variables) and I this: $variables['TheTest'] = '<pre>Poop!</pre>'; just to see if I could pass ANYTHING back and forth... Then in my tpl.php file I added: <?php print render( $TheTest ); ?> and I got NOTHING. I even tried $content['TheTest'] and got nothing... I'm thinking something is going wrong with my &$variables...

Comment: Could it have ANYTHING to do with the fact that my function THEMENAME_field_CONTENT_TYPE(&$variables) is not technically inside the 'template.php' but rather inside a file I called template_netrunner_card.php and then included FROM template.php?

Comment: Nope. I moved it and removed the include statement and it still doesn't work. I am so completely lost... ugh.