# Theme specific form field for custom content type

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I have created a custom content type and added some fields to it. I want to theme one of the fields which I added from the "Manage Fields" section.

I want to remove the div wrappers when the form field is rendered.

Is there any form field specific theme function which I can override in `template.php` and make my changes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in template.php, you would use `THEMENAME_field__fieldname__contenttypename()` as theme function. If you like to use a special template file, you would name it field--fieldname--contenttypename.tpl.php and put it into yours themes template folder.

All needed information can be found in [Drupal API documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7).

Comment: I want to  theme the form field in Add Form and not while viewing the page. I tried this before and was not working.

Comment: Note: If you are making changes to the node edit forms, and are using an admin theme. It is the admin theme template.php that you will need to change.

Comment: @Villie sorry, you are right, that is indeed for outputting the fields value.

Maybe this question was [answered before here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33253/how-do-you-theme-a-content-types-create-edit-form-in-drupal-7)?

Comment: And another one [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27947/preprocess-function-per-content-type).